# MongoDB Get Average Visits Per Day In Every Month

Tags: python, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I need to create a query to retrieve the average number of visits per day, grouped by year and month.
I'm quite new to mongoDB and I dont really know how to do this.

This is my database model (code is in python):

```
class Visits(Document):
    year = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    month = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().month)
    day = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().day, unique_with=('month', 'year'))
    visits = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Visit'))


class Posts(Document):
    year = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().year)
    month = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().month)
    day = IntField(default=datetime.datetime.now().day, unique_with=('month', 'year'))
    posts = ListField(EmbeddedDocumentField('Post'))


class Visit(Document):
    user = ReferenceField('User')
    time_spent = IntField(default=0)


class Post(Document):
    id = IntField(primary_key=True)
    user = ReferenceField('User')
    number_of_comments = IntField(default=0)
    number_of_clicks = IntField(default=0)


class User(Document):
    id = IntField(primary_key=True)
    created_at = DateTimeField(default=datetime.datetime.now())
    test_subject = IntField(default="0")
```

Comment: http://api.mongodb.org/python/current/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.aggregate

Comment: I'm using Mongoengine, cant really find how to execute a raw aggregation to run on PyMongo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get the raw "collection" object as implemented by the pymongo driver using the `._get_collection()` method on the class.

So if you have a MongoDB 2.6 or greater version you can use the [**`$size`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/size/) operator with aggregation:

```
result = Visits._get_collection().aggregate([
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": "$year",
            "month": "$month"
        },
        "visits": {
            "$sum": { "$size": "$visits" }
        }
    }}  
])
```

Prior to MongoDB 2.6 you need to [**`$unwind`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the array first in order to get the count of elements.

```
result = Visits._get_collection().aggregate([
    { "$unwind": "$visits" },
    { "$group": {
        "_id": {
            "year": "$year",
            "month": "$month"
        },
        "visits": { "$sum": 1 }
    }}
])
```

Probably a good idea to restrict your range by using the [**`$match`**](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) operator. PyMongo and MongoDB style queries are a bit different to the django style, so you might want to familarize yourself with the [standard query operators](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/) from the MongoDB manual.

Comment: Thank you so much, was trying to find it all day.

Do you think the schema is ok for analytics?

God bless you!

Comment: @EduardoAlves If you are regularly querying over data in ranges then it is always best to add to "pre-aggregated" collections in there somewhere. You can still use the aggregation framework to periodically build these and even possibly work further aggregation on the compacted results. What you actually need depends on the usage patterns of your application and the size of data you are dealing with.